# Asp.Net Reflection Count properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.reflection

I'm using a ASP.NET web service and I am having a problem with touring foreach properties through Reflection
I pick the result that sends me the Web service and get into shape and start looking there to actually match a name with what I want (In my case, a record)
The problem is that when attempting a GetType (). GetProperties () returns me "Can Read, Can Write" properties and not my properties
This is a Code:

```
Resultado = ExpService.getAllExpedients(Valor, FechaInicial, FechaFinal, ExpedienteInicial, ExpedienteFinal, true);
                CountExpedients = Resultado.Expedient.Count<ExpDetail>();
                ViewState["CountExpedients"] = CountExpedients;
```

If I look directly through the string property returns me correctly

```
var Info = Resultado.Expedient[i].Nif.ToString();
```

But I do not know how from here to perform a loop me collect all the properties and their values

[All Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i621v.png)
I tried using several forms (including GetValue (this, null)) but do not succeed in any way and is the last thing left for me to finish this part of the project.
Does anyone would be kind enough to explain me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it found the solution to the whole problem
I attacked another method that I had which returns the file and pick it succeeds so

```
var Detalles = ExpService.getExpDetail(NºExpediente, Valor);
foreach (PropertyInfo Info in Detalles.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (Info.GetValue(Detalles, null) != null) 
                    {
                        var Informacion = Info.GetValue(Detalles, null).ToString();
                    }
                }
```